# Update whole entity by specific column using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm receiving list of campaign with **external id** and I want to save them by this id. We have an entity with **id**, unique **externalId** and **name** columns.

```
@Entity
public class Campaign {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    UUID id;

    @Column(name = "external_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    Long externalId;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

}
```

Let's say we already have some campaign in database. Then we are getting list of the **existed campaign** with a **changed name** and a **new one**. If I try to use JPA save method it throws unique constraint exception. Is that possible to save this list by **externalId** column using hibernate? Is there some approach? Now I first find each campaign to make sure it already exists and if it does I update all fields. In a real case I have more then 1 column that could be changed and tons of campaigns to save/update.

Comment: Load an existing entity from the database and, in the same transaction, modify the entity. Changes to the entity will be committed when the transaction is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have data against externalId then simply update the data. for this u have to check if externalId is present or not. if present then use update query if not then use insert query.